# Trigonometry: finding the length of an arc.

Tags: trigonometry

I am currently preparing for a trig test. And I am stumped on one of the questions that involve a bicycle wheel problem. The question is

" A carbon bicycle wheel has a diameter of 700 millimeters with 16 spokes evenly distributed around the rim of the wheel. What is the length of the rim subtended by any 2 adjacent spokes."

I'm a bit dubious with my answer which is approximately 274.8.

I got this solution by taking the radius of the bicycle which is 350, and then found the circumference of the wheel with $2\pi \bullet \frac{2spokes}{16spokes} $.

after that, I used the arc length formula $ s = \theta \bullet r$ which  was $ 350 \bullet \frac {\pi}{4}$ to find $s \approx 274.8$

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Between two spokes there is only one interval.
So the angle is
$\dfrac{2\pi}{16}$
radians.

Between $n$ spokes there are $n-1$ intervals.
So the angle for this case is
$\dfrac{(n-1)\pi}{16}$
radians.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes more sense because the distance between the two spokes is one interval and the answer seems a bit not proportional to the wheel. Thank you!